# Empty metrics in sonar for web and javascript projects

Tags: javascript, jsp, maven, web, sonarqube

### Initial post

I use several tools for my Continuous Integration :

- Maven 3.0.4
- Sonar 3.3
- Sonar Web Plugin 1.2
- Sonar Javascript Plugin 1.1
- Jenkins 1.486

Everything works fine for Java projects and XML projects.

I'm having trouble with Javascript and web projects. Projects are created in Sonar but they are empty.

Here is a sample of stacktrace for a javascript project

> [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.0-beta-2:sonar (default-cli) @
>   MyProject ---
>
> [INFO] Sonar version: 3.3
>
> [INFO] [15:59:24.937] Create JDBC datasource for
>   jdbc:mysql://sonar-02:3306/sonar
>
> [INFO] [15:59:41.190] Initializing Hibernate
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.318] -------------  Analyzing MyProject JS
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.573] Quality profile :
>   [name=myProfileJavascript,language=js]
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.612] Configure maven plugins...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.653] Compare to previous analysis (2013-02-08)
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.672] Compare over 5 days (2013-02-03, analysis of
>   2013-02-07 12:29:08.0)
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.682] Compare over 30 days (2013-01-09, analysis of
>   2013-02-07 12:29:08.0)
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.877] Initializer ProjectFileSystemLogger...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.878] Excluded tests: [**/package-info.java]
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.881] Source directories:
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.881]
>   C:\Work\Workspaces\Intellij\MyProject\src\main\java
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.881] Test directories:
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.882]
>   C:\Work\Workspaces\Intellij\MyProject\src\test\java
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.882] Initializer ProjectFileSystemLogger done: 5 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.882] Initializer MavenInitializer...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.884] Java source version: 1.6
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.884] Java target version: 1.6
>
> [INFO] [15:59:43.884] Initializer MavenInitializer done: 2 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.183] Sensor JavaScriptSourceImporter...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.335] Sensor JavaScriptSourceImporter done: 152 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.335] Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.520] Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor done: 185 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.520] Sensor JsTestDriverSurefireSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.526] Sensor JsTestDriverSurefireSensor done: 6 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.526] Sensor JsTestDriverCoverageSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.584] Sensor JsTestDriverCoverageSensor done: 58 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.584] Sensor CpdSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.585] SonarBridgeEngine is used
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.642] Sensor CpdSensor done: 58 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.642] Sensor ProfileSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.725] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 83 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.725] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.752] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 27 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.753] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.791] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 38 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.791] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.820] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 29 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:44.820] Sensor Maven dependencies...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:48.148] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 3328 ms
>
> [INFO] [15:59:48.517] Execute decorators...
>
> [INFO] [15:59:48.856] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse
>   `http://sonarServer:9000`
>
> [INFO] [15:59:48.857] Executing post-job class
>   org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
>
> [INFO] [15:59:49.140] Executing post-job class
>   org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
>
> [INFO] [15:59:49.154] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-01-11
>   and 2013-02-07
>
> [INFO] [15:59:49.156] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-12-14
>   and 2013-01-11
>
> [INFO] [15:59:49.157] -> Keep one snapshot per month between
>   2011-04-08 and 2012-12-14
>
> [INFO] [15:59:49.157] -> Delete data prior to: 2011-04-08
>
> [INFO] [15:59:49.163] -> Clean MyProject JS [id=57524]
>
> [INFO] [15:59:49.167] <- Clean snapshot 1690793

I can see that sonar is using C:\Work\Workspaces\Intellij\MyProject\src\main\java

In my pom I have tested several properties without changin sonar behaviour.

```
 <sonar.javascript.sources>src/main/webapp</sonar.javascript.sources>
 <sonar.sources>src/main/webapp</sonar.sources>
 <sources>src/main/webapp</sources>
```

It's the same  problem with web projects.

Any Idea ?

Thank you in advance.

### EDIT 11/02/2013 - After Fabrice - Sonar Team comment

I created a new pom (pom-web.xml) with the following informations

```
<properties>
    <sonar.branch>JS</sonar.branch>
    <sonar.language>web</sonar.language>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

It seems that the sources directory changed but metrics are still empty.

> [INFO] [12:11:54.486] Execute
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test done: 545 ms
>
> [INFO] [12:11:54.486] Execute maven plugin maven-surefire-plugin done:
>   545 ms
>
> [INFO] [12:11:54.486] Initializer JacocoMavenInitializer...
>
> [INFO] [12:11:54.486] Initializer JacocoMavenInitializer done: 0 ms
>
> [INFO] [12:11:54.486] Initializer ProjectFileSystemLogger...
>
> [INFO] [12:11:54.487] Excluded tests: [**/package-info.java]
>
> [INFO] [12:11:54.487] Source directories:
>
> [INFO] [12:11:54.487]
>   C:\Work\Workspaces\Intellij\MyProject\src\main\webapp

Same behavior with web and JS.

### EDIT 11/02/2013 : Solution found

I needed to have one pom file. So I managed sonar properties thanks to profiles. As "sourceDirectory" is not re definable within profiles, I use a custom properties.

the property "sonar.branch" enables me to have several sonar entries for my project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>fr.test</groupId>
<artifactId>MyMultiLanguageProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <ci.build.sourceDirectory>src/main/java</ci.build.sourceDirectory>
    <ci.build.testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</ci.build.testSourceDirectory>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${ci.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${ci.build.testSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>CI-WEB</id>
        <properties>
            <sonar.branch>WEB</sonar.branch>
            <sonar.language>web</sonar.language>
            <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
            <ci.build.sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</ci.build.sourceDirectory>
            <ci.build.testSourceDirectory>src/test/webapp</ci.build.testSourceDirectory>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>CI-JS</id>
        <properties>
            <sonar.branch>JS</sonar.branch>
            <sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
            <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
            <ci.build.sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</ci.build.sourceDirectory>
            <ci.build.testSourceDirectory>src/test/webapp</ci.build.testSourceDirectory>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You currently have to create other POMs (or profile in your POM) if you want to analyse JS and Web projects. In those new POMs (or profiles), you will set the "sourceDirectory" tag to the correct folder, and you won't forget to specify "sonar.language" in the properties. Also, those new POMs/profiles should change the artifactId so that you have different projects in Sonar.

Then you can run "mvn clean sonar:sonar -f pom-javascript.xml" (new POM) or "mvn clean sonar:sonar -Pjavascript" (using a profile).

In a near future, Sonar will natively support multi-language projects. Until then, you have to use this hack.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. But I must do something wrong, I'll add details above.

Comment: There's something wrong with your config, as it seems that Sonar still considers your project as a Java project. Could you take a look at the following examples: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/javascript and https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/web

Comment: Thank you again. I've reverted all my changes and made a light pom-web.xml. It worked perfectly. Now, I'm trying to make it work with profiles, which I think, will be easier to maintain (don't kown how the jenkins "perfom maven release" plugin handle several pom files). The last problem is to change the "sourceDirectory" within a profile.

Comment: Problem solved thanks to you Fabrice. I edit the initial post to add solution.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam do you have any example configuration for the same setup using a sonar runner? One module with two languages that can be run separately like in this maven configuration?

Comment: The following should answer your question: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-source-files-in-same-directory

Comment: I confirm. multi-languages projects are now supported and Javascript Plugin is working as-is (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Plugin).