# sonar-maven3-plugin Javascript not respecting -Dsonar.source

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a project that contains javascript files in src/main/webapp/js.  In order to analyze these, I am executing the following:

```
mvn install org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5:sonar -Dsonar.branch=js -Dsonar.language=js -Dsonar.sources=src/main/webapp/js -Dsonar.login=sonar -Dsonar.password=sonar
```

I have also attempting this with: -Dsonar.importSources=true

When I execute this, I get a build success. However, when I look at the js project I created, it contains no data.  When I look at the logs, I see this which leads me to believe that the sonar.sources property is not being read.

```
[INFO] [17:38:42.273] Base dir: /home/mw-sandbox/.jenkins/jobs/ssi-wdf-re/workspace 
[INFO] [17:38:42.273] Working dir: /home/mw-sandbox/.jenkins/jobs/ssi-wdf-re/workspace/target/sonar 
[INFO] [17:38:42.273] Source dirs: /home/mw-sandbox/.jenkins/jobs/ssi-wdf-re/workspace/src/main/java, /home/mw-sandbox/.jenkins/jobs/ssi-wdf-re/workspace/target/generated-sources/wsimport 
[INFO] [17:38:42.273] Test dirs: /home/mw-sandbox/.jenkins/jobs/ssi-wdf-re/workspace/src/test/java 
[INFO] [17:38:42.273] Binary dirs: /home/mw-sandbox/.jenkins/jobs/ssi-wdf-re/workspace/target/classes 
[INFO] [17:38:42.273] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For now, it is not possible to use properties such as "sonar.sources" when the analysis is triggered with Maven. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters. But it should be soon. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4536.

So, you can work with Maven profiles to override source directories.

Comment: I agree with the first statement, but not the second. You cannot override the sourceDirectory element of the maven build tag, which you would need to do to use a maven profile to override the source directory. Scroll about 1/2 way down this webpage to verify: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: @user26859 You're wrong - it is possible to use profiles to override value of sourceDirectory in Maven. And here is how:

    <build>
      <sourceDirectory>${src}</sourceDirectory>
    </buil>
    <properties>
      <src>src/main/java</src>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>js</id>
        <properties>
          <src>src/main/webapp/js</src>
        </properties>
      </profiles>
    </profiles>

Answer (score 0):

A work-around have been found in this post : 
[Empty metrics in sonar for web and javascript projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775802/empty-metrics-in-sonar-for-web-and-javascript-projects)

It is a bit messy with the maven profiles, but I tried it, it does the job...